# Как отключить float если не работает clear?

Tags: html, css, float, site, clear

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.info {
    background: url('../css/background.png');
    height: 487px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}


.info__image {
    width: 275px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    right: 25px;
    top: 9px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}


.info__image h2 {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
    bottom: 56px;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="info__image">
                <a href="#" class="info__image" style="display: block;"><img src="css/new.png">
                    <h2>Новинки</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="info__image">
                <a href="#" class="info__image" style="display: block;"><img src="css/sale.png">
                    <h2>Знижки</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="info__image">
                <a href="#" class="info__image" style="display: block;"><img src="css/gift.png">
                    <h2>Подарунки</h2>
                </div>
            <div class="info__image">
                <a href="#" class="info__image" style="display: block;"><img src="css/top.png"> 
                    <h2>Бестселери</h2>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: "Отключить"? А почему бы просто не убрать его?

Comment: он нужен для горизонтального выравнивания блоков, я не могу отключить его для дальнейших секций

Comment: Почему не используете ```display: flex``` или ```display: grid``` вместо этого?

Comment: возможно у меня не правильно написан сам код, но при этих командах все блоки просто становятся в вертикальный ряд

Comment: а есть пример, как именно нужно сделать?

Comment: добавила картинку, с моим кодом так получилось, но все дальнейшие секции прижимаются к левому краю

Comment: @sima потому что flex/grid вешается на контейнер, а не сам блок. А эти дочерние блоки уже сами выстраиваются как нужно. Просто почитайте документацию на мозилле с примерами, всё сразу станет понятно

Comment: Обратите внимание, у вас блок и дочерняя ссылка имеют один и тот же класс info__image. Оставьте этот класс только у блока, а для h2 уберите position:relative и clear:both

Comment: И сам clearfix у вас не правильно применен

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого вам нужно?

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item__circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item__label {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__circle">Value</div>
    <div class="item__label">label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__circle">Value</div>
    <div class="item__label">label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__circle">Value</div>
    <div class="item__label">label</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__circle">Value</div>
    <div class="item__label">label</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- В данный момент у вас не закрыт тег  `<a href="#" class="info__image" style="display: block;"><img src="css/new.png">`. Тег `а` парный тег `<a href=""></a>`.
- Еще присутствует лишний `</div>`.

---

У лучше уходить от `float` и использовать `flex или grid`.

Документация по [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Документация по [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

---

По вашему изображению сделал такой пример:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info__image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.info {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #673ab7;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.info__image h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="info">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="info__image" title="Подробнее">
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629426293928-8a3a220eb283?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80"></div>
      <h2>Новинки</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="info__image" title="Подробнее">
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653783319756-c8b1839d9de3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=464&q=80"></div>
      <h2>Знижки</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="info__image" title="Подробнее">
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644418792211-5df0394a1fd5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80"></div>
      <h2>Новинки</h2>
    </a>
    <a class="info__image" title="Подробнее">
      <div class="circle"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657000529335-5c1bf76204af?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80"></div>
      <h2>Знижки</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```